# Thermostat calling for heat but brand new Taco Zone Switch not opening?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, heating, boiler

I have a trusty old gas boiler that succeeded at providing baseboard heat to 2 zones for years. I recently had a third zone added. This is a 2-wire, heat-only system. The electrician tried and couldn't figure out how to get an ecobee to work with the third zone, so he gave up but said it's wired for a basic thermostat, all I need to do is connect it at the wall.

I connected the basic thermostat using the Blue as the "white" wire and Red as RH. I'm not sure I used the correct wires. But it will successfully will call for heat because it clicks the thermostat on. But the pipes that run to the third zone don't get hot. I manually flipped the Taco valve to "open" and all of the hot water ran to the third zone.

So it seems like this means the Zone Switch isn't working. It's a brand new switch, so it's gotta be the wiring.

Here is the breakdown of wires on the 3rd Taco, according to the numbers on the switch:

1. Blue, connected to Blue from thermostat
2. White, connects with #2 on 2nd zone Taco switch
3. Two wires: Red, connects to Red from thermostat. Another Red, connects to #3 on 2nd zone Taco switch

There's a transformer that has a bunch of connections that run to the other Zone Switches. The photos include the 3rd zone switch, the thermostat connection, the transformer, the diagram the electrician drew, and a photo of the 3 zone setup (3rd zone Taco is the top one). Electrician's diagram mentions the white wire from the thermostat, but that's unconnected. Maybe that's where this went wrong?

[image: third zone taco]

[image: transformer]

[image: third zone wall thermostat]

[image: electrician diagram]

[image: furnace, third zone switch at top]

Comment: I'd start by measuring the voltage at the Taco connections when thermostat is on (and off), and comparing that with the ratings for the Taco valve.

Comment: The Taco needs 24v. If all I'm doing is running it to the wall thermostat, I get why it's not working. So would it mean I'd need to connect the red #3 Taco wire to the TT white wire nut off the transformer? Then wire the red wall thermostat wire to that as well?

Comment: @jflbball -- can you get us measurements of the voltage between #1 and #3 on the Taco valve when the thermostat is calling for heat, please?

Comment: @threephaseeel I tested connections. 1+3 reads 0 when the thermostat is set to "heat on". 2+3 and 2+1 reads between 2-5 on the multimeter when heat is called.

Comment: @jflbball are those voltage readings, or...?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sorry I'm just getting the hang of this multimeter. I redid the readings: for zone 3 (the one I'm trying to figure out): 2+3 and 2+1 reads 2.8v. 1+3 reads 0v.

By contrast, when I fire up zone 2, then 2+3 reads 23.8v, 2+1 reads 24v, and 1+3 reads 49v. So I take it that my zone 3 1+3 seems to be the issue?

Comment: That 49V at zone 2 seems just...wrong, like you shouldn't be able to get that reading without a second power source somewhere in the system

Comment: There is a transformer and a lot of wires going into zone 2.